# Running Java multi threaded process and top shows single thread

Tags: java, multithreading, limit

I hope I'm asking it correctly, we have a process which has 10 threads, on one server the process finishes after 4 minutes (which is great) and on the other it takes 40 minutes, now on the slower one I see the following when running "top":
Tasks: 255 total,   **1 running**, 242 sleeping,  12 stopped,   0 zombie

which basically makes sense as only 1 thread is working.

Is there any configuration for the ux which might limit the work of multi-threaded processes?

Comment: I think it is system dependent whether Java threads are mapped directly to system threads, so they might not show up. Have you checked using a Java tool like JVisualVM?

Comment: Check default options of `top` command, there are many reason why it could hide your threads

Comment: hi Axel/Germann, thanks for the quick reply :)
i can see on the other server that more threads are running so I don't think it is hidden, is there any configuration for that?

Comment: Are you using `top -H`? That will show all native threads which I believe most JVMs use for Java threads.

Comment: hi cyon, it's not that..
look at CPU
Cpu(s):  0.4%us,  0.5%sy,  0.0%ni, 98.8%id,  0.2%wa,  0.1%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
idle most of the time

Answer (score 0):

A Tasks translates to a process not thread. A single Process will have multiple Threads. In top you should see the number of threads running displayed.

Comment: Hi mig, thanks for answering, indeed i see only single thread, where in the code we create 10 threads, on other servers it is running in parallel and I can see the CPU works harder:
Cpu(s): 68.6%us,  4.8%sy,  0.0%ni, **21.8%id**,  0.0%wa,  0.2%hi,  4.7%si,  0.0%st